# How to send/ Upload file without using FORMDATA in jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

How to send/Upload file without using FORMDATA in jquery ajax? Because IE does not support FORMDATA...

here is the working code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpload").on("click", function () {
        var file_data = $("#UploadedFile").prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field          

        var form_data = new FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
        form_data.append("file", file_data)              // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
        form_data.append("user_id", 123)                 // Adding extra parameters to form_data
        $.ajax({
            url: "/User/UpdateImages",

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: file_data,                         // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
            type: 'post',

            success: function (data) {

                if (data.imageURL != "") {

                    // $("#imageDiv").html("<img name=\"CompanyLogo\" width=\"213\" height=\"204\" src= " + data.imageURL + "/>");
                    $("#CompanyLogo").attr("src", data.imageURL);

                }



            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.imageURL + "error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```