# Upload file without using Formdata in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to upload files without using formdata in Angular Js. I have checked the below links, which have not helped:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432299/upload-file-using-jquery-without-using-html5
- [How to send/ Upload file without using FORMDATA in jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959590/how-to-send-upload-file-without-using-formdata-in-jquery-ajax)
- [How can I upload file in JavaScript and PHP without using FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325761/how-can-i-upload-file-in-javascript-and-php-without-using-formdata)

I do not want to use any plug-in, and cannot use iframes. I want to upload single file. I have the service created as below, to which I have to pass the image data.

```
myAPIService.postUploadImage = function (formdata) {
        var request = {
            url: urlBase + 'UploadImage',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }

        }
        return $http(request);
    };
```

The UI is defined as below:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="imageUploadfile" name="Imagefile" accept="image/*" />
 <input type="button" name="imageUploadButton" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
```

Requesting Admin/moderators to not mark it as duplicate, as I have tried most of the links, but that has not worked.

How to upload single file in AngularJS without using plugins,iframe and which works in IE 11, Chrome.
Thanks

Comment: Try ng-flow. Its very nice plugin, with minimal setup.

Comment: Is there no other way, other than using a plugin? I would like to do a simple upload without using plugin or iframe. Thanks

Comment: You can use jquery to upload the files. See this https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Hi @Majid.. The URL which you have provided uses formdata, which I do not want to use

Comment: @venkat14 have you got the solution?